# Mounting overlayfs with root patition stop working (for me)

Tags: linux, mount, overlayfs

I am trying to use rootfs as a lower point of new overlay mount point. Then I chroot to a new mount point and use it for test some packages and selflearning without harming real system. This was worked for me a couple month ago but now it didn't. (My old hdd died so I buyed a new one and reinstall linux)

When I trying to mount

```
sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o,lowerdir=/,upperdir=upper,workdir=work processdir
```

I get the following error:

```
mount: /test/processdir: mount(2) system call failed: Too many levels of symbolic links.
```

And dmesg says

```
overlayfs: overlapping upperdir path
```

But any mount point will be child for rootfs and overlapping will be present always in that sheme.

Is I am doing something wrong? Is there a way to mount rootfs in that sheme?

- My system is Archlinux. Linux kernel version 5.5.13.
- Virtualbox and so on isn't a solution for me.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=146d62e5a5867fbf84490d82455718bfb10fe824 (might have been backported to a few previous)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot @A.B

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use kernel 5.10 and above. Debian 11 uses this kernel by default, and Debian 10 has it in the backports repository.